# Change font/symbol size of window elements

Tags: windows-10

Somehow an shortcut increased my font/symbol size of Windows. This only affects Windows element (e.g. Titlebar, Desktop) but not other applications like Chrome.

The "Scale an layout" is at 100%

What is the shortcut to reset the size?
[image: Problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem with Winaero Tweaker. there you can reset any of the current settings with one click.

I used it because e.g. reseting `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics` to the default values only fixed the font in the title bar.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the control panel under display. Within that dialog see the heading "Change only the text size". I think "Menus" will change the font you describe.

```
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display
```

[image: control panel]

Comment: Display is not an menu. It was removed by an Windows 10 Update.